# connect to interface gateway from private subnet aws

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-vpc, vpc-endpoint

I have a private subnet in my VPC on AWS. I have a java application uploaded on Lambda in that subnet, from which I am trying to connect to SQS via interface endpoint. In my java application I connect to SQS by :

```
AmazonSQS sqsClient = AmazonSQSAsyncClientBuilder
                .standard()
                .withEndpointConfiguration(new AwsClientBuilder.EndpointConfiguration(ENDPOINT_URL_SQS, REGION))
                .withCredentials(new EnvironmentVariableCredentialsProvider())
                .build();
```

```
sqsClient.sendMessage(new SendMessageRequest(SQS_URL, objectMapper.writeValueAsString(sqsMessageObject)));
```

but I get
 `Unable to execute HTTP request: Connect to sqs.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com:443 failed: connect timed out` in Lambda logs.

I gave access on 22 port for tcp traffic in my security groups. Is there anything i am missing? Thank you in advance.

Comment: What are SGs on your interface endpoints?

Comment: @Marcin my SG on interface endpoint allows all traffic from anywhere (0.0.0.0/0)

Comment: What ports and nacls are you using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was using queue URL in the code. I changed it to endpoint URL and it worked.